# I am plotting a graph by reading a csv file. I wanted to convert ticks of 1st-axis into 2nd x-axis by the conversion 1239.8/x-original tick

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, visualization

```
import os
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

        # Plotting for each CSV file
        for i in range(len(x_values)):
            plt.plot([x_values[i], x_values[i]], [y_values[i], 0], marker='', linestyle='-', color='black')
            plt.annotate(f" {state[i]}", (x_values[i], y_values[i]), textcoords="offset points", xytext=(0,5), ha='center')

    # Overall Plotting
    plt.xlabel('2nd Column')
    plt.ylabel('3rd Column')
    plt.title('Vertical Lines Connecting 2nd and 3rd Column Values for All CSV Files')

    # Create a second x-axis
    ax2 = plt.gca().twiny()

    # Set ticks for the second x-axis using the reciprocal of the original x-axis values
    original_ticks = plt.gca().get_xticks()
    ax2_ticks = [1 / val if val != 0 else 0 for val in original_ticks]

    # Set ticks and labels for the second x-axis
    ax2.set_xticks(original_ticks)
    ax2.set_xticklabels([f"{round(1239.8/tick, 2)}" if tick != 0 else '0' for tick in ax2_ticks])
    ax2.set_xlabel('Secondary X-Axis (Derived from 2nd Column with Reciprocal)')

    plt.show()
```

I am using this code and trying to plot 2nd x-axis with respect to first x-axis ticks. the conversion I want to achieve is 1239.8/ticks of x-axis. How do I achieve this? I am a beginner. My data is 3 column in which I give first column as an argument to plot 2nd and 3rd value on graph as straight line or bar graph.

Comment: Your title should be concise and clear and not just your first paragraph. Please read and follow [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The third sub-heading entitled 'Write a title that summarizes the specific problem' is particularly important in your case.